# What is the best way to respond to a Notification Action in my ViewModel?

Tags: android, timer, architecture, notifications

I have a timer app that I want to be able to control from a notification if the user backgrounds the app. All of the timer logic and actions, such as pausing and playing, are within a viewmodel of mine.

At the same time I have different action receivers on my notification, including pausing and playing. Given that I can't exactly just make my entire viewmodel static, what would be the best way architecturally speaking to communicate and respond to these notification actions in my viewmodel?

Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually quiet simple once I took a step back, even re-reading what I wrote above.

The main problem was that I was even doing the timer logic in the viewmodel to begin with. Given that the timer needed to be interacted with by more than the view, it made more sense to move the timer logic to its own class that could then be called on by my notification actions as well as by my viewmodel.